# NOT NULL constraint failed: home_profile.user_id

Tags: python, django

### I have written an extension of the Django `auth.user` model which adds *middle_name* and *phone* fields to the model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return(f'{self.user.username} profile')
```

---

### I am using the following forms to accept input from the user.

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2']

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=10, min_length=10)
    middle_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=True)

class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['middle_name', 'phone']
```

---

### The view for the register route is as follows:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        username = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        user_form.save()
        profile_form.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Welcome { username }! Your account has been created. Sign in to continue.')
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'home/register.html', { 'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form })

else:
    user_form = RegistrationForm()
    profile_form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'home/register.html', { 'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form })
```

---

### This is contents of the signals.py file

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

---

The issue is while a row for the user is getting created in the Profile model, data is not getting written into the fields of the row. I am seeing a `Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: home_profile.user_id`

Comment: By using a signal, you will create a `Profile` object, but the `profile_form` will be unaware of that, and thus create *another* one that does not link to the user.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what would you suggest ? I think this is precisely what is happenning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a signal, you will create a `Profile` object, but the `profile_form` will be unaware of that, and thus create *another* one that does not link to the user. You thus might want to remove the signals. [Signals are often an *anti-pattern*](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/), and furthermore there are several ORM calls that can *circumvent* the signals.

If you *remove* the signals, you will still need to link the `Profile` object wrapped in your `profile_form` to the user, you do this with:

```
# remove the signal that constructs a Profile

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()  # ← assign the user to a variable
            profile_form.instance.user = user  # ← set it as user of the profile
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Welcome {user.username}! Your account has been created. Sign in to continue.')
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        user_form = RegistrationForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, 'home/register.html', { 'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form })
```

Comment: thanks. right now, the form fields appear in this order, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password1`, `password2`, `middle_name` and `phone`. I was wondering if it is possible to rearrange them so that middle name is between `first_name` and `last_name`  in the form on the frontend ? thanks in advance

Comment: @s13rw81: what if you specify the fields as `fields = ['first_name', 'middle_name', ...]`?

Comment: @WillemVanOsnem I tried to move _middle_name_ and _phone_ to the `RegistrationForm` form and commented the fields list in the `ProfileForm` but it is throwing an error. ```django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (phone, middle_name) specified for User``` Also removing the fields list from any of the Meta classes is throwing an error as well.

Comment: @s13w81: ah the two are of different forms yes. Well in that case you can render the forms manually (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) and thus render the fields from the two forms in the order you want.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I learnt a lot. You are a legend.!